# Printing to console from a function within a function

Tags: r, function, printing

I would like to make this function within a function print to console:

```
somefun <- function(x) {
    otherfun <- function (x) {
        print(x)
    }
}
somefun("It works!")
```

What would be the best way to make this happen?

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding this correctly. Do you want to call `print(x)` which is inside `otherfun` function without running `x <- x + 1` line?

Comment: So since the input for `somefun` and `otherfun` is the same. Why not put `print(x)` as 1st line in `somefun` itself?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. It asks to print `x` in the console which my answer does. It is difficult to imagine things which are not included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the inner function in the outer function?

```
somefun <- function(x) {
  otherfun <- function (x) {
    print(x)
  }
  otherfun(x)
}

somefun("It works!")
#[1] "It works!"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! But wouldn't this be an issue when `otherfun` does more than just printing?

Comment: Can't think of a reason where it could be a problem. If `print` is inside `otherfun` you need to call it I think. Do you have a different example to explain this ?